# Vaadin view scope object destruction problem

Tags: spring, scope, garbage-collection, vaadin

I use Vaadin version 8.15 (vaadinCompatibilityVersion=7.7.11). I use Oracle JVM Java jdk11.

I have this code:

```
public class MyComponent extends CustomComponent {
     @PreDestroy
     public void destruction(){
         //writing log
         ...
     }

}
```

```
public class MotherComponent extends CustomComponent{

    ...
    protected MyComponent myComponent;
    ...
    public MotherComponent(){
        super();
        myComponent = new MyComponent();
    }
    ...
    }

    ...
}
```

When Garbage collection is done myComponent don't write log.
If myComponent is injected with Spring in MotherComponent with scope vaadin-view, does write the log.
Why?
I expect that the output of these two cases should be the same, but it doesn't.

I expect that the output of these two cases should be the same, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`@PreDestroy` is a Spring feature that is only used for Spring managed beans. When you're using the `new` keyword to create an instance of the component, then you are manually managing that instance rather than allowing Spring to do it.